# CSS to php table result

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a piece of php code,

which generates some results from mysql and adds them to a two column table which works fine.  I have then added the following css class to the column.

```
td.manu {
background: url("../images/manu_button.fw.png") no-repeat; 
height: 87px; 
width:478; 
font-size:48px; 
font-family:Arial,
 Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 color:#309;}
```

Now if the results are returned and there are two columns of data the tables fit perfectly however if it returns one column the text is in the middle of the page:

Please see the links below:

http://www.qrrw.net/R - this shows one column

http://www.qrrw.net/p  - shows two coulmns

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Try using `min-width: 478px` instead of just `width: 478px`.

Comment: You are missing a 'px' with `width` property.

Comment: BTW, that background image can be recreated entirely with CSS now with the help of box-shadow, linear-gradient (as a bg image), and border-radius.

Comment: Please post all relevant code directly in this question, so that it will be useful to people who are having the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, your table is in a `<div>` defined as

```
<div align="center">
```

The `align` attribute is deprecated - you should not use it anymore.

Add the following styles to that `div`, i.e.:

```
<div style="text-align: left; margin-left: 300px;">
```

That will give you a result similar to what you had with both columns in place. You may have to increase the margin to obtain the desired effect.

**Note:** this is a band-aid solution... If you don't want to change your styles too much - add some logic to detect the situation where you have only one column, and insert empty `<td>` in your result to compensate for the missing cells. This way your output should still follow the styling you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution.

Let's say the array result is stored as follow $result.

Do the following

```
if (count($result) == 1){
echo <td class="manu">LINK HERE</td><td class="manu"></td>    </tr>
}
```

Basically what you are doing is just adding one extra column if the result is 1

Tho for a better use you should always add an extra  in the end if the result is odd.
So that in every  you would have 2 .
So your code will be like this before closing the  tag

```
if (count($result) % 2 == 1){
echo <td class="manu">LINK HERE</td><td class="manu"></td>    </tr>
}
```

And finally may i recommend that you switch to a pure CSS layout using just divs rather tables ??
It will make your code easier to edit and update design and layout wise.